# Correctness-Proof of a greedy-algorithm for minimum vertex cover of a tree

Tags: algorithms, trees, greedy-algorithms

There is  a greedy algorithm for finding minimum vertex cover of a tree which uses DFS traversal.

1. For each leaf of the tree, select its parent (i.e. its parent is in minimum vertex cover).
2. For each internal node:
   if any of its children is not selected, then select this node.

How do I prove that this greedy strategy gives an optimal answer? That there is no vertex cover smaller in size than the one that the above algorithm produces?

Comment: I don't think the logic for the 2nd step is correct. If you consider a degenerate tree with 6 nodes going down all the way right (label them 1-6 corresponding to their depth). 

Then the first step of your algorithm will pick node 5. The second step will then *possibly* pick the first node (root) and then the second node (child) OR the third node. However, this is incorrect since you only want to pick node 2 and node 5 for a correct solution.

Comment: @miguel.martin If the Vertex Cover just contains vertices numbered 2 and 5, the edge between node 3 and 4 won't be covered.

Answer (score 11):

We first observe the following: There is an optimal cover $C$, and no leaf is in $C$. This is true since in any optimal cover $X$ you can replace all leaves in $X$ with their parents, and you get a vertex cover which is not larger than $X$.

Now take any optimal cover $C$ that does not contain leaves. Since no leave is selected, all parents of the leaves have to be in $C$. In other words, $C$ coincides with the greedy cover on the leaves and their parents. Next, we take out all edges that have been covered already. We can now apply the same argument again: In the remaining tree, no leaf needs to be selected, but then their parents have to be selected. And this is exactly what the greedy algorithm does. (A vertex becomes a leaf iff all of its children are selected in the previous step.) We repeat this argument we determined a complete vertex cover.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Construct a matching of the same size as your vertex cover by matching each vertex in the cover with an unselected child. Prove that $|M| \leq |C|$ for any matching $M$ and any vertex cover $C$. Conclude that the vertex cover is minimum and the matching is maximum.